# C# object list that can be declared, returning an iteration of items to be inserted into the main list

Tags: c#, object, constructor, declaration

C# question.

I need to fill my main object property, that is a list of a custom object, but at some point, I need to add to this list a replication with a specific declaration, but I don't want to have to add a line per each item, when there's only and index change on the specific ID of the item in the list.

How to do that with a loop that adds items to a list on the constructor declaration (or so).

Metacode sample:

```
private static readonly MainObject myObject = new()
{
  Type = "OP",
  Group = "FD",
  Items = new List<SubObject>
  {
    new SubObject("Tag.Count", 0),
    new SubObject("Tag.Min", 0),
    new SubObject("Tag.Max", 100),

    // Sub list starts here, from 1 to 10
    new SubObject("Tag.Pos.1", 1),
    new SubObject("Tag.Pos.2", 4),
    new SubObject("Tag.Pos.3", 9),
    ...
    new SubObject("Tag.Pos.10", 100),
    // Sub list ends here with 10 items

  }
}
```

So, my SubObject list contains what could be solved as a iteration of a single line, but how to do it in this declaration, ... something like, ... were i is a loop item from 1 to 10:

```
            ... new SubObject(`Tag.Pos.$i`, $i^2)
```

Looking for a solution that in the end, returns a sub list that can be added and included in the main list when declaring the object, recognized and accepted by the constructor:

Something that, just line in JavaScript can return something similar to:

```
...[new SubObject(`Tag.Pos.$i`, $i^2)]
```

Comment: Can you get those Tag values from a file or db or from an API endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try with for loop

```
private static readonly MainObject myObject = new MainObject
{
    Type = "OP",
    Group = "FD",
    Items = GenerateSubList()
};

private static List<SubObject> GenerateSubList()
{
    List<SubObject> subList = new List<SubObject>
    {
        new SubObject("Tag.Count", 0),
        new SubObject("Tag.Min", 0),
        new SubObject("Tag.Max", 100)
    };

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        subList.Add(new SubObject($"Tag.Pos.{i}", i * i));
    }

    return subList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't dynamically add items in the declaration block, but you could add items after construction using Linq:

```
  Items = new List<SubObject>
  {
    new SubObject("Tag.Count", 0),
    new SubObject("Tag.Min", 0),
    new SubObject("Tag.Max", 100),

  }

  myObject.Items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1,10).Select(
    i => new SubObject($"Tag.Pos.{i}", i*i)
  ));
```

or move the "Items" generation info a function that returns a varaible number of items in a list:

```
private static List<SubObject> GetItems(int numItems)
{
    List<SubObject> items = new List<SubObject>
    {
        new SubObject("Tag.Count", 0),
        new SubObject("Tag.Min", 0),
        new SubObject("Tag.Max", numItems*numItems)
    };

    items.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(1,numItems).Select(
      i => new SubObject($"Tag.Pos.{i}", i*i)
    ));

    return items;
}
```

and call that in your constructor:

```
private static readonly MainObject myObject = new()
{
  Type = "OP",
  Group = "FD",
  Items = GetItems(10)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Items = new List<SubObject>()
{
    new SubObject("Tag.Count", 0),
    new SubObject("Tag.Min", 0),
    new SubObject("Tag.Max", 100)
}
.Concat(Enumerable.Range(1, count).Select(x => new SubObject($"Tag.Pos.{i}", x*x))))
.ToList();
```

You can `Concat` to your list and create a new one in one statement.

Whether this is more readable then the other solutions is up to you. If it is more complex then your example here, an extra function as suggested in the other answer might be preferable for readability purposes.